# Connect R with Oracle through Oracle developer tool

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I followed instruction about how to connect R with Oracle using ROracle. However the connect rejected with error "ORA-12541: TNS: no listener".

I think this may due to I connect Oracle using Oracle SQL developer on my desktop, but the real Oracle DB should be on some remote clusters. Wonder who can tell what to do?

I checked some threads online and someone said it is due to listener not running on the Oracle server. But I can use Oracle SQL Developer to connect the server.

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I thought I wrote it. I am using ROracle to connect. But the problem is the remote connection between Oracle server and my client.

Comment: No, it returns ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error

Comment: hmmm you might need to consult your db administrator

Comment: If not R, can you connect it using SQL developer? If you can't best person would be your database admin.

Comment: I have no problem using SQL developer to connect. But using R or command line, both have some issue with TNS